# 2 columns on desktop one column on mobile with flexbox

Tags: css, sass

I´m trying to generate a list of users (2 per row on desktop and 1 per row in mobile)

this is my markup

```
<div class="users">
    <div>user 1</div>
    <div>user 2</div>
    <div>user 3</div>
    <div>user 4</div>
</div>
```

this is my SCSS

```
.users {
    display: flex;
    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

I´m not sure if column-count is meant to be used like this.

Comment: no,its not here is link to read more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

what you should do is change the width of the div till you reach the desired result

Comment: This is not valid CSS. A CSS property cannot contain a @media property.

Comment: sorry typo. is SCSS (updated!)

Answer (score 0):

did You mean something like that?

HTML:

```
  <div class="users">
      <div>user 1</div>
      <div>user 2</div>
      <div>user 3</div>
      <div>user 4</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.users {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 900px;
}
.users div {
  background-color: teal;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

demo here -> https://codepen.io/AdamKniec/pen/PoPxXvJ

Comment: This is not valid CSS. You cannot nest CSS properties.

Comment: Thats why I said that it’s SCSS ;)

Comment: Yes but the question is not tagged as SCSS and not mentioned anywhere. You should not assume because he may have copy/pasted it from somewhere without knowing what he was doing.

Comment: Non problemo. Added as css

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bootstrap grid system like this .

```
<div class="users row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-12" >user 1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">user 2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">user 3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">user 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's an overkill for me . Using Bootstrap just for that ??

Comment: yeah want to stay away from bootstrap.